# Цикл foreach c условием

Tags: php

Есть такая задача - циклом `foreach` пройтись по массиву `$_POST` и исключить из обработки значения двух ключей - как это можно реализовать?

Пробовал вкладывать условие внутри цикла:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if($key !== 'action' || $key !== 'security'){               
        update_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_'.$key, $value);
    }
}
```

не срабатывает - ключи не исключаются из обработки.

Comment: K != 1 ИЛИ K!=2 всегда истинно. если K=1 то оно не равно в это время 2 и наоборот. замените `||` на `&&`

Comment: Спасибо, недосмотрел

Comment: `!in_array($key, ['action','security'])` будет несколько элегантней, имхо

Comment: @teran вот только `in_array` это еще один цикл... так что два цикла вместо одного взамен на сомнительную элегантность....ну не знаю))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский от части согласен, что доп. цикл это не очень хорошо. С другой стороны, при увеличении числа таких  условий код станет нечитаемым. +В пхп такого. наверное, нет, но в компилируемых языках магия компилятора порой неплохо разворачивает подобные конструкции.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if($key == 'action' || $key == 'security') { continue; }
    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_'.$key, $value);
}
```